# Google Analytics Profile Filtering with Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics

I have a two different sites that checkout on the same eCommerce site. There's sitea.com siteb.com and checkout.com. They are set up like this:

```
    siteb.com --> sitea.com --> checkout.com
```

Most traffic is on stiea.com and customers checkout directly from there to checkout.com. Those using siteb shop and build a cart on siteb and then when they checkout they go sitea which then takes them to checkout.com. I have cross domain and ecommerce tracking up and working perfectly for sitea.com and checkout.com and so setting it up for siteb.com isn't an issue. Where this issue comes is that I want to be able to look at the traffic on just siteb.com AND the eCommerce for siteb and just siteb, basically excluding all the eCommerce from stiea. When I test it out I get all of sitea's traffic as well as siteb's. I've looked everywhere but can't find any kind of solution. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near as I can figure, there's no way to setup a segment or filter that only includes pages whose first page was on siteb.com.  One idea is to set a session/visit scoped custom variable on the first page of visit, with a value of for example "siteb" if starting on siteb.com, or 'sitea" if on sitea.com.  Then you should be able to go to your custom variable report and go to the siteb.com entry and break down by all pages.